# outputStream.write has has buffer overflow?

Tags: java, io

I'm trying to send a `byte[]` to a serial port. However `outputstream.write(byte[]);` only works when `byte[].length` contains less then about 100 bytes.

Just to know:

using spring source tool suite (Eclipse)

JDK 1.7

DEFAULTBAUDRATE is set to 9600

the `byte[]` never contains more then 476 bytes

NRSerial is a library offering a platform in-depended version of the 'deceased' vaxx.comm library

there is no hardware connected to the serial port

I'm sniffing the serial port with an application (a bit like wireshark)

I'm still a student so the code may suck :P

This code works:

```
NRSerialPort port = new NRSerialPort(portname, DEFAULTBAUDRATE);
port.connect();
OutputStream outputStream = port.getOutputStream();
for(int i = 0; i<bytes.length; i++){
    if(i%10==0){
        Thread.sleep(1);    
    }
    outputStream.write(bytes[i]);
}
outputStream.flush();
outputStream.close();
port.disconnect();
```

Advantage: works on all systems
Disadvantage: may sleep unnecessarily

And so does this:

```
NRSerialPort port = new NRSerialPort(portname, DEFAULTBAUDRATE);
port.connect();
OutputStream outputStream = port.getOutputStream();
for(byte b : bytes){
    outputStream.write(b);
}
outputStream.flush();
outputStream.close();
port.disconnect();
```

Advantage: no unnecessarily sleeping
Disadvantage: may not work on fast systems because they can process the for each much faster

But the code below will fail if bytes contains more then about 100 bytes:

```
NRSerialPort port = new NRSerialPort(portname, DEFAULTBAUDRATE);
port.connect();
OutputStream outputStream = port.getOutputStream();
outputStream.write(bytes);
outputStream.flush();
outputStream.close();
port.disconnect();
```

Although `write(byte[])` is a valid method in the sun library

I have some ideas about this:

- I overflow the output buffer, the baudrate is to low to send this data at once
- `write(byte[])` does not cut the `byte[]` to smaller pieces

You might wonder why I ask this question if I got a working solution. Well:

I want to know which one of my solutions is better and/or if there is a other/better way to do this. besides why make a method `write(byte[])` if its processing capability's depend on hardware (at least say so in the JavaDoc?)

Comment: You say the code fails.  How does it fail?  Does it raise an exception, or are you not receiving all the bytes on the socket reading your output?  Your question needs a bit more context.

Comment: the code that 'works' shows like this in the sniffer:            Port opened by process "javaw.exe" (PID: 2060)
 3C 00 00 00 00
port closed     the code that does not only opens and closes

Comment: Just to make sure. Are you sure that the bytes[] array is populated properly BEFORE these snippets? It might explain if another stream is writing to it at the same time.

Comment: yes im sure besides in your case it would not matter how large the array is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming I've googled the correct code, this does not look like a problem with Java but with the implementation of the `NRSerialPort` library.

Diving into the code, I can see that [SerialOutputStream](http://code.google.com/p/nrjavaserial/source/browse/trunk/nrjavaserial/src/main/java/gnu/io/RXTXPort.java?r=116#1128) provides the implementation of the `OutputStream` and it calls two different methods depending on whether the `write(byte)` or `write(byte[])` method is used:

see [here](http://code.google.com/p/nrjavaserial/source/browse/trunk/nrjavaserial/src/main/java/gnu/io/RXTXPort.java?r=116#601)

```
protected native void writeByte( int b, boolean i ) throws IOException;
protected native void writeArray( byte b[], int off, int len, boolean i ) 
    throws IOException;
```

Without digging into the native code, I would surmise that there may be a bug in the implementation of the `writeArray` method.

Comment: i posted this bug on the nrserialport wiki,thanks for the help;)